# How to disable browser CPU throttling on SetTimeout?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, firefox, browser

When the browser is minimized or the tab is on the background they set `setTimeout` to a `minimum` of `1 second`
example code:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

async function doStuff() {
    let p0 = performance.now();
    await wait(100);
    let p1 = performance.now();
    console.log('time',(p1-p0));
    await doStuff();
}
```

When the tab or the browser is on focus the `console.log` prints `100`, when it's minimized `1000`.

I also tried to use a web worker:

```js
const cross_origin_script_url = "https://filebin.net/w73l748cgfap1qau/test.js?t=29itk5mt";

const worker_url = getWorkerURL( cross_origin_script_url );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );

const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

worker.onmessage = async function() {
    let p0 = performance.now();
    await wait(100);
    let p1 = performance.now();
     console.log('time',(p1-p0));
}

//worker.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( evt.data );
//URL.revokeObjectURL( worker_url );

// Returns a blob:// URL which points
// to a javascript file which will call
// importScripts with the given URL
function getWorkerURL( url ) {
  const content = `importScripts( "${ url }" );`;
  return URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ content ], { type: "text/javascript" } ) );
}
```

filebin `test.js`:

```js
// worker.js
setInterval(function() {
    postMessage('');
}, 1);
```

But it's very inconsistent, time using web worker:

[image]

How I can disable/bypass it?

Comment: What makes you think this is CPU throttling? .... Some and largely most modern browsers limit activity of timers to save resources when the tab is not active.

Comment: I know it, but I don't want it setting the timeout to a minimum of 1second independent if it's to save resources.

Comment: Search SO. I've seen this before somewhere on here, and it was solved.

Comment: Use SSE or WebSockets. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/#state-polling